# How to set two separate hypotheses in parallel

Tags: lists

I am looking for ways to show two separate hypotheses in a paper. The hypothesis is directed to different targets, thus I need to indicate the S or B in the number. How could I make it?

Hypothesis S1

Hypothesis B1

Hypothesis S2

Hypothesis B2

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe with a `description list?

Comment: Do you have any font requirements? E.g., should the headers "Hypothesis S1", "Hypothesis B1", etc be rendered in bold? Next, which font do you want to use for the bodies of the hypotheses: upright, italics, something else? Are you loading a package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem` and, if so, have you defined an environment called, say, `hypothesis`? Please be specific.